# tensorflow does not recognise 2nd GPU (/gpu:1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multiple-gpu

I am trying to use 2 GPUs, tensorflow does not recognise the 2nd one. the 2nd GPU is working fine (in widows environment)

```
When I set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 and run the program I see RTX2070 as GPU0
When I set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 and run the program I see GTX1050as GPU0
When I set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 and run the program I see RTX2070 as GPU0
```

so basically, TF does not recognise GPU1, it one GPU at the same time (GPU 0)
Is there any command to manually define GPU1?

uninstalled and re-installed, Cudann, python 3.7, tensorflow and keras (GPU versions). I am using anaconda on windows 10. tried to change the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to 0, 1. I dont see any error, but the 2nd GPU does not appear anywhere in python.

the main GPU is RTX2070 (8GB) and 2nd GPU is GTX1050 (2GB). Before i submit i spent sometime searching for solution and did whatever I could find on the internet. drivers are up to date, 64bit version anf latest versions of the software are installed. I dont see any issue, beside not appearing the 2nd GPU.

The codes are working fine on first GPU, both have > 3.5 computational capacity.

Comment: What happens it you set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to just `1`? Do you get again the first GPU only, the second GPU shows up or simply no GPUs?

Comment: When I set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 and run the program I see RTX2070 as GPU0 When I set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 and run the program I see GTX1050as GPU0 When I set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 and run the program I see RTX2070 as GPU0

so basically, TF does not recognise GPU1, it one GPU at the same time (GPU 0) Is there any command to manually define GPU1

Comment: Adding this at the bggining of the code resolved the issue                                                       import os
os.environ["TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT"]="2"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1"

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, you can post an answer to your own question with it (and accept it).

Answer (score 1):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section (Thanks M Student for sharing solution), for the benefit of the community.

Adding this at the beginning of the code resolved the issue

```
import os 
os.environ["TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT"]="2" 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1"
```